# Debugger in NB 7.3 not working

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I changed from NB 7.2.1 to 7.3 and my debugger stopped to work. When I try to run debugger it say:

```
Attaching to localhost:8787
Connection refused.
```

Have been tried to add exception for that port in firewall. Did not changed anything.

Anybody have a clue what can be reason for this?

Comment: How are you running your application and the debugger?

Comment: I am deploying app to jboss server and debugger from NB attaching to port 8787. It was working and suddenly just stopped. Was looking on internet but did not manage to find solution...

Comment: It seems you're starting application without remote debuggin info...